# Gemfire get the error from cqEvent

Tags: c++, c, listener, gemfire

I have a registered `cqListener` on a region. How can i get the actual error why `onError` had occured from the parameter of the method `const gemfire::CqEvent& cqEvent`?

I checked the documentation but it seems they don't have any method on the `CqEvent` class that can acctually retrieve a possible error.

Answer (score 1):

@Alex 
Hi Alex,
See what documentation says:

```
/** 
   * This method is invoked when there is an error during CQ processing.  
   * The error can appear while applying query condition on the event.
   * e.g if the event doesn't has attributes as specified in the CQ query.
   * This event does contain an error. The newValue may or may not be 
   * available, and will be NULLPTR if not available.
   */
  virtual void onError(const CqEvent& aCqEvent);
```

It explicitly mentions "This event does contain an error". and CqEvent also does not contain method to get the error.